# Complete an oracle sql, add new colums with the sum of other column

Tags: oracle, pentaho

One doubt, I am not an expert in sql oracle. I have the following sql:

```
select p.pname as Project, t.pname as Type, c.cname as component, w.timeworked/ 3600 as hours
from jira.jiraissue j,
jira.worklog w,
jira.project p,
jira.issuetype t,
jira.component c,
jira.nodeassociation na
where w.issueid = j.id
and J.PROJECT = P.ID
and na.source_node_id = j.id
AND na.sink_node_entity = 'Component'
AND na.source_node_entity = 'Issue'
and na.sink_node_id = c.id
and t.id = j.issuetype

and w.author = (case when $ {Author} = 'All' and then the author else $ {Author} ends)
and p.pname = (case when $ {Project} = 'All' then p.pname else $ {Project} final)
and t.pname = (case when $ {Type} = 'All' then t.pname else $ {type} final)
and c.cname = (case when $ {Component} = 'All' and then cname else $ {Component} final)
and to_char (w.startdate, 'yyyy-mm-dd')> = $ {FromDate}
and to_char (w.startdate, 'yyyy-mm-dd') <= $ {ToDate}
```

el resultado es la siguiente tabla:
[image]

I would like to add a column with the sum of all rows HORAS and another with the sum grouped by COMPONENTE. Can someone give me advice if I can do what I want and how?

Comment: As a remark : the main use of Pentaho Data Integrator is to get rid of these complex (and ugly and hard to maintain) SQL query. You may also be quicker with 4 lookup steps...

Comment: is dificult to me create de different dimensions in workbench

Comment: Do like everybody, don't use the workbench. Type the xml in a editor, and use the Workbench only to remove syntax errors. However, my remark was to use the Pentaho Data Integrator to make all the data massage, and push the resulting flat table to the Report Designer.

Comment: You say spoon? that I am new in this world and I do not know much

Comment: Yes. Spoon is the user interface of the Pentaho Data Integrator, also know as PDI or Kettle. Prepare your data with it, and give it to the other tools. You have a nice Start-up here: https://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Getting+Started [Do not worry about the note about the version. The icon did change, but it is still valid]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Analytic functions might come in handy here:

```
SELECT
    p.pname AS Project,
    t.pname AS Type,
    c.cname AS component,
    w.timeworked / 3600 AS hours,
    SUM(w.timeworked / 3600) OVER () AS sum_all_hours,
    SUM(w.timeworked / 3600) OVER (PARTITION BY c.cname) AS sum_by_component
FROM jira.jiraissue j
... (the rest of your current query)
```

Comment: another cuestion, how can i do to add a new column grouped by component and type? example: Peticion->Motor Facturacion->150h , peticion-> facturacion->20h, Bug->Motor Facturacion->10h, Bug->facturacion->8h....

Comment: I don't understand what else you want to do here. Maybe edit your question and show some sample data.